# How to get more than 100 results when searching for repositories with the Java GitHub API?

Tags: java, github, github-api

I'm currently using the org.eclipse.egit.github.core-2.1.5 GitHub API for Java with the goal of searching for all repositories on GitHub using Python.

I know how to do the search, but the `RepositoryService.searchRepositories(query)` method only returns 100 results. If I redo the search, the same results are given back. Is there any way to get the next 101-X search results?

Is there any way to use a command similar in functionality to `curl https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/Go?language=Go` within the Java GitHub API? If so, what method would offer this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by [the code](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/RepositoryService.java#L477), there are several overloaded variants of `searchRepositories`, one of which accepts a `query` parameter, a `language` parameter and a `startPage` parameter. This means you should be able to run the query that you specified by using:

```
RepositoryService.searchRepositories("Go", "go")
```

If you then want to get more results, you would specify the page as well:

```
RepositoryService.searchRepositories("Go", "go", 2)
RepositoryService.searchRepositories("Go", "go", 3)
...
```

Unfortunately I cannot see a way for you to tell how many pages there actually are. The [code](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/GitHubService.java#L126) used by `searchRepositories` to do the request suggests that the first request should in fact return all the results across all the pages, but if you are only getting 100 results back, then it seems this is not the case. You might just have to keep trying later pages until you get no results back.

Comment: Thanks for the help and this definitely works, but it is only working for me up to the tenth page of results (1000 results), and then I get the exception `org.eclipse.egit.github.core.client.RequestException: Only the first 1000 search results are available (422)`. Do you know if there's any way to get through this issue? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I think this is a [limit of the API itself](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/): "To satisfy that need, the GitHub Search API provides up to 1,000 results for each search." Anyway, happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you feel my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.